# mypy: Incompatible return value type

Tags: python, oop, type-hinting, mypy, python-dataclasses

So, I have one dataclass as follows

```py
@dataclass
class DataObj:
    """ DataObj creates an object for each record in data
    """
    name: str
    profit: int
    space: float
```

I have another container class that holds the objects of above class

```py
class DataContainer:
    """ Data Container class holding objects of DataObj class
    """
    def __init__(self, data_tuple_list: List[Tuple[str, int, float]]) -> None:
        self.container = []
        for data_tuple in data_tuple_list:
            self.container.append(DataObj(*data_tuple))

    def __getitem__(self, n: int) -> Type[DataObj]:
        return self.container.__getitem__(n)
```

However, when I check the code using mypy, I get following error

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "DataObj", expected "Type[DataObj]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

My python version is `3.8.10`.

Question: How to fix the error.

### EDIT

1. If I use `self.container: List[DataObj] = []`, I get `error: Incompatible return value type (got "DataObj", expected "Type[DataObj]") Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)`
2. If I use `self.container: List[Type[DataObj]] = []`, I get `error: Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "DataObj"; expected "Type[DataObj]" Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)`.

Comment: Make `DataObj` instead of `Type[DataObj]` to be the return type of `DataContainer. __getitem__`

Comment: @hoefling, this works, you can put this as an answer. However, I have one question, Shouldn't I be using `Type[DataObj]` with Python 3.8.10 (I guess, its ok to use it for 3.10+)??

Comment: No. Your `__getitem__` impl returns `DataObj` instances, not `DataObj` classes. You would have a `Type[DataObj]` returned if you would have a code like `self.container. append(DataObj)` or `o = DataObj(...); self.container. append(o.__class__)` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you didn't type hint your container as well (`self.container`) so mypy looks at it as a `List[Any]` and probably can't see that it only contains values of type `DataObj` so when you return something from the list, mypy can't be sure that it's something of type `DataObj`

Try:

```
class DataContainer:
    """ Data Container class holding objects of DataObj class
    """
    def __init__(self, data_tuple_list: List[Tuple[str, int, float]]) -> None:
        self.container: List[DataObj] = [
            DataObj(*data_tuple)
            for data_tuple in data_tuple_list
        ]

    def __getitem__(self, n: int) -> Type[DataObj]:
        return self.container[n]
```

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried and it worked for me:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Tuple


@dataclass
class DataObj:
    """ DataObj creates an object for each record in data
    """
    name: str
    profit: int
    space: float


class DataContainer:
    """ Data Container class holding objects of DataObj class
    """

    def __init__(self, data_tuple_list: List[Tuple[str, int, float]]) -> None:
        self.container = [
            DataObj(*data_tuple)
            for data_tuple in data_tuple_list
        ]

    def __getitem__(self, n: int) -> DataObj:
        return self.container[n]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_tuple_list_concrete = [
        ('test1', 1, 1.1),
        ('test2', 2, 2.2),
        ('test3', 3, 3.3),
        ('test4', 4, 4.4),
        ('test5', 5, 5.5),
    ]

    dc = DataContainer(data_tuple_list_concrete)
    print(dc[0])
    print(dc[1])
    print(dc[2])
    print(dc[3])
    print(dc[4])

"""
Output:

DataObj(name='test1', profit=1, space=1.1)
DataObj(name='test2', profit=2, space=2.2)
DataObj(name='test3', profit=3, space=3.3)
DataObj(name='test4', profit=4, space=4.4)
DataObj(name='test5', profit=5, space=5.5)
"""
```

```bash
$ mypy main.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Ok, it works on my system as well.

Comment: Great. I also suggest type hinting the container (```self.container```) in case it's intended to only contain values of type ```DataObj```.

Comment: I'd rather type `data_tuple_list` as `collections.abc.Iterable[tuple[str, int, float]]`: you really use neither mutability nor length, but only rely on value being iterable of said tuples.